# Problema al imprimir una serie factorial

Tags: c++

Quiero imprimir esta serie factorial : 2, 3, 8, 30 en C++. Puse esta línea para sacar la serie y no funciona:

```
return factorial (número) + factorial (numero-1);
```

Esto es para sacar los valores de la serie en base a los términos del 1 al 10. Por ejemplo, si se usa el número 4, nos da 30 porque el 30 es el cuarto elemento de la serie : (2, 3, 8, 30), y 4! + (4-1)!

Éste es mi código:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

unsigned long factorial( unsigned long);

int main(){

  for( int i=0; i<=10;i++)
    cout<<i<<"!"<<factorial (i)<<endl;

  return 0;
}

unsigned long factorial (unsigned long numero) {
  if( número<=1)
    return 1;
  else 
    return factorial ( número) + factorial ( numero-1);
    // Se pone esta función, para que en base al término de la serie, se realice 
    // la operación, es decir si se usa la cuarta posición nos da 30, 
    // el 30 es el cuarto elemento de la serie : (2,3,8,30 ), 4! + (4-1)!
}
```

Comment: si puedes especifica cual es el problema para que puedas recibir ayuda más rápido

Comment: No necesitas colocar en el título de tu pregunta palabras como ayuda, estamos en SO, un lugar que nacio para ello, por lo que es redundate. Los títulos son usados para la búsqueda por lo que deben ser genéricos y concretos, por favor evite ello, lea [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

unsigned long factorial(unsigned long);
int main(){
    for(int i=1; i<=10; i++) {
        cout << i << "!" << factorial (i) + factorial (i - 1) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


unsigned long factorial (unsigned long numero) {
    if ( numero <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else { 
       return  numero * factorial ( numero-1) ;
    }
 // Se pone esta función, para que en base al término de la serie, se realice la operación, es decir si se usa la cuarta posición nos da 30, el 30 es el cuarto elemento de la serie : (2,3,8,30 ), 4! + (4-1)!
}
```

Supongo que el programa que necesitas este, para obtener la serie (2,3,8,30). La serie tal que teniendo n perteneciente a los números del 1-10, queremos obtener n! + (n-1)!

En la aportación de turkey faltaba la parte de la suma y el factorial de n - 1. También, al poner como parámetro de la función "unsigned long", te dará un error de ejecución si empiezas en i = 0, porque el primer parámetro que le pasarás es -1.

Comment: Gracias Eduardo !!

Answer (score 0):

```
// Example program
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

unsigned long factorial( unsigned long);
int main(){
    for(int i=0;i<=10;i++) {
        cout<<i<<"!"<<factorial (i)<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}


unsigned long factorial (unsigned long numero) {
    if ( numero <= 1) {
        return 1;
    } else { 
        return  numero * factorial ( numero-1) ;
    }
// Se pone esta función, para que en base al término de la serie, se realice la operación, es decir si se usa la cuarta posición nos da 30, el 30 es el cuarto elemento de la serie : (2,3,8,30 ), 4! + (4-1)!
}
```

En la segunda condición estabas sumando en lugar de multiplicar, recuerda que eso es el factorial. ademas estabas retornando dos veces el factorial `return factorial ( número) + factorial ( numero-1);` que tampoco seria valido porque el factorial es n * n-1 * .... . Recuerda tambien tabular tu codigo, esto permite que tu y otras personas puedan leerlo con facilidad.

Comment: apenas veo que tu serie no corresponde a una serie factorial. Estas seguro que necesitas  el factorial?